# Manage Filter ID Gmail

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, filter, gmail

I am trying to create a filter for every people's email in a group. However, sometimes the a person's email can changes like adding new email or change to another mail email. That means I have to update the filter accordingly. I tried to create filter with ID that with the person's name. So I can retrieve that filter to modify it. However, it seems that the Gmail filter's ID are created automatically.

```
var filter = Gmail.newFilter()
var email = 'something@some.com'
filter.id = 'person'
filter.criteria = Gmail.newFilterCriteria()
filter.criteria.query = email
filter.action = Gmail.newFilterAction()
filter.action.addLabelIds = ['Label_1']
Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.create(filter, 'me')
```

When I get back the filter, it will say that it cannot be found

`var filter2 = Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.get('me', 'person')`

This will return `Not Found` error even I can see the filter in setting in my Gmail. The actually ID for the filter I created above is `ANe1Bmgel8OKlEXD-uArX77ISk35Lph1MbWWjA`.

My question is what's the good way to manager filters through changes, keep them updated?

Comment: Why not use the reply from the `create` request?

Comment: To clarify my comment, if you immediately `.create` a filter and then query for it in a separate `.get`, you will often receive the "not found" error because you are racing Google - Google has to propagate the existence of that filter to the various server endpoints. However, if you bound the reply from the call to `.create`, you obtain the new filter information in the API response: `var created = Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.create(...);` and can store the created ID as desired. It isn't clear in your question how you are testing the `.get` call, so please clarify your situation.

Comment: I tested the `.get` call _after_ I can confirm that the filter already exist when I look at the setting manually (via clicking in a web browser). The id I retrieved by going through all filters and get all the info in that filter and I can say without any uncertainty that it's the filter that I created via script. Also, there is no filter have the ID of `person`, which I set via script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the API documentation for a [`Filter` resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters):

> **id: *string*** The server assigned ID of the filter.

Thus, you cannot assign the ID, and any value you set for it in the call to `.create` is ignored.

You can still programmatically retrieve this filter, using [`.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters/list) and `Array#filter`, e.g.

```
function getAllFilters_(userId) {
  const options = {};
  const filters = [];
  do {
    var search = Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.list(userId, options);
    if (search.filter && search.filter.length) {
      Array.prototype.push.apply(filters, search.filter);
    options.pageToken = search.nextPageToken;
  } while (options.pageToken);
  return filters;
}
function getFiltersWithCriteria_(filterList, criteria) {
  // `criteria` is an object of parameters that must be exactly matched in the filters' criteria property
  const props = Object.keys(criteria);
  const matches = filterList.filter(function (gFilter) {
    // gFilter is a https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters#resource
    var fCriteria = gFilter.criteria;
    return props.every(function (prop) {
      return criteria[prop] === fCriteria[prop];
    });
  });
  return matches;
}
function foo() {
  const filters = getAllFilters_("me");
  const matched = getFiltersWithCriteria_(filters, {
    from: "george@example.com",
    hasAttachment: true
  });
  console.log({message: "Matching filters", matches: matched});
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the information. But I don't think remembering the exact criteria of a filter is a good way to manage it.

Comment: There is no other way to identify a filter other than using some part of it. There are other filter properties beyond `criteria`, but you will still need to know some portion of them. Considering your use case - a change of email - you can certainly query for filters that match the old email and modfiy them to use the new one.

Comment: I don't really think this is a good way to manage filter. However, it seems that it's the best way (as far as available functionality). So I will mark this as an answer if no-one else say anything in a week.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.create(filter, 'me');
```

Try:

```
var filterProps = Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.create(filter, 'me');
var filterId = filterProps.id;
```

Per the API documentation for [creating a filter](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters/create),

> If successful, this method returns a Users.settings.filters resource in the response body.

The code above worked for me in a similar situation. To keep track of the filterId outside of Gmail, you could then tie the person's name to the id via the property service:

```
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(nameVar, filterId);
```

and then retrieve it like so:

```
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(nameVar);
```